# How to handle Authentication pop up

Tags: selenium

Please have a look at below image

[image]

I need to send email, password and click on OK. I tried Action , Robot class. But did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alert, Robot and username/password in URL does not work so you may need to try by creation profile and calling that if it work in this or else go for AutoIT..

I prefer, create your own firefox profile by providing name. [Here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows) is the steps

Once profile is created, navigate to URL manually and provide those authentications and Saved those. As you saved so next time if you start the same profile, it does not asks, correct?

So call that saved profile

```
 ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();

 FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("savedProfile");

  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 1):

you can use like below:-

```
driver.get("http://UserName:Password@Example.com");
```

Give your username in place of username, same for password and change example.com with your website

OR

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);      
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(**username**, **password**));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. But unfortunately did not work. I need to load  driver.get("https://service.something.com:2096/"); page, then it asks for UserAndPassword.

Comment: yeah I tried but username and password contain special chars like @#, so I am getting invalid url error in browser.